# Power supply circuit concerns

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-design, lithium

**TL;DR: Go to the bulleted list below.**

As a weekend project I tried to design a simple power supply (without sofisticated switching mode ICs, since they are very hard to find where I live). So after some calculation and study, I came up with the following circuit, it is supposed to be a 7V 4A power supply for small projects, enough to power some microncontrollers (5/3.3V 100mA), small DC motors (5V 1A), and charge a li-ion battery :

[image]

I am aware of the nonidealities of these components, so **extreme** precision is not a important role here, since I don't intend to replace my good ol' bench supply. I will wire a digital voltmeter/ammeter to the output for calibration.

That said, I would like to ask some questions:

- About the resistors R3 and R6, is it correct to pull up a MOSFET gate for such operations? Should I pull it down instead? Or remove the resistors? I am concerned about LM324 output sink/source capabilities with those resistors.
- Also, in my output circuit, should I add other components to improve safety and stability?
- And last but not least: is it safe to charge a li-ion battery with this circuit? (Considering a 2200mAh battery, with 4.2V max voltage) If not, how could I improve this circuit to achieve this?

Any help/advice will be very apprecieated!

**Datasheets:**

IRF540 - https://www.vishay.com/docs/91021/91021.pdf

LM324 - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf

1N4732A & 1N4737A - http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet_pdf/bkc-international-electronics/1N4728_to_1N973B-1.pdf

Comment: Why are all your schematics drawn sideways? Convention for legibility is positive supply at the top and negative (and usually ground) at the bottom. All your ground symbols are sideways.

Comment: Well, the original circuit was following the convention. I just moved the blocks to fit them in a rectangle with a aspect ratio of **around** 1:9; so it would be proportional to most screens when there is a taskbar or title bar, and fit in the entire view. But will rotate it in just a sec!

Comment: What are R1 and R4 for? They will dissipate lots of power at 4A

Comment: I inserted your rotated images.  They aren't any larger than the original sideways jobbies, and they are a damned sight easier to read.

Comment: Thanks JRE. If any component value is hard to read (due to overlapping), I could do some tweaks in it.

Comment: Some thoughts (I may change this to an answer). The pullups are not necessary (but pulldowns of the order of 100k might be useful for startup performance); the feedback loops will definitely need compensation (or at least analysis).

Comment: Sean87, in my calculations, there is around 1/10 of a watt in both resistors. All of my resistors are 1/4 watt. I think that it is okay for a Zener with a 5mA expected current.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I would really appreciate if you could wrap the "compensation" part of your comment in an answer. I don't know much about it and will be very helpful for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> About the resistors R3 and R6, is it correct to pull up a MOSFET gate for such operations? Should I pull it down instead? Or remove the resistors? I am concerned about LM324 output sink/source capabilities with those resistors.

R3 and R6 have no effect, except maybe during startup. I would make R6 a pulldown to help start the output at 0V.

> Also, in my output circuit, should I add other components to improve safety and stability?

As drawn, the current control is probably unstable because it has gain but no compensation. Add a resistor (10k?) between the shunt and the inverting input, and a small capacitor (100p?) between the output and inverting input of U1B. This slows down the current control by making fast changes to its output appear immediately at its inverting output and will prevent it from oscillating.

Also, the output resistance will be 1 ohm, because the voltage control doesn't consider R4. Overall I don't think this is a good setup. You should look at some other bench power supply schematics and see what they do.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer! I will add your improvements to the circuit! So, after these modifications, will it be okay to charge a battery in such circuit? As I pointed out in the last item. PS.: I've looked at some circuits and I just tried to simplify then, trying to keep the same functionality. Now I am not sure if I did it right '-'

Comment: In case of failure of the feedback, R3 and R6 could turn their MOS on permanently causing short circuits and burnout. (if I understand the schematic correctly)

Comment: @Fredled if by failure of the feedback you mean U1 catching fire, yes. Otherwise U1's output dominates.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong: R3 and R6 will turn their MOS on permanently and immediately causing 12V to load without any regulation, (only R4 would put some limitation). It's like connecting OUTB to 12V directly. U1 and U2 have no effect.

Comment: @Fredled U1's output impedance is what, 100 ohms open loop?

Comment: At first I misunderstood what U1 and 2 were for. After looking at the datasheet I rectified in my last comment. IMO, U1 and U2 have no effect as long as you keep R3 and R6. Mosfets will be always ON. Remove these resistors and U1 and U2 will do their job.

Comment: @Fredled When U1 outputs 0V, R5 and R6 form a voltage divider, the voltage at the gate is 0.2V. R6 has basically no effect.

Comment: This is true if U1 switch pin 1 or 7 to ground when output is low (0V). I didn't inspect the datasheet enough to answer this. But if it doesn't then there is no voltage divider. Anyway these resistor connections are useless at best.